# Error stylesheet when using rowspan in table tag?

Tags: html

I have a sample code:

```
<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
           <th></th>
           <th>Brand name</th>
           <th>Model name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
           <td rowspan="2"></td>
           <td>HTC</td>
           <td>P6300,
               Advantage X7500
           </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td rowspan="7"></td>
           <td>Samsung</td>
           <td>
              M2710 Beat Twist,
              I7500 Galaxy,
              M7500 Emporio Armani,
              Galaxy Ace Plus S7500,
              S5610,
              P7500 Galaxy Tab 10.1 3G,
              S7230E Wave 723
           </td>
       </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

But result is error stylesheet:
[image: error]

OUTPUT is:
[image: output]

Comment: Umm, why do you have empty `<td>` and `<th>` tags?

Comment: what are row spans for... formatted http://jsfiddle.net/rWMw6/

Answer (score 1):

You must have the same number of `td` tags in each row. This includes what you have with `rowspan`.

You can't have `rowspan` in the first row and then have a td in that spot in the next. Take out `<td rowspan="7"></td>` because there is a `td` in the row above with a `rowspan` attribute already accounting for this one.

In your code, you have the rowspan 2 td (the thin one) and then your rowspan 7 one (empty square to the left of Samsung), and then the two `td`s with the data. This extra td (the rowspan 7 one) pushes the others to the right.

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/ewusef)

The other thing you might want is the model name text is all in one line. You should put `<br />` after each line to make it show like that in the browser.